# Android: Populate ListView (JSON) based on 2 spinners selection

Tags: android, json, listview, android-spinner

Firstly please don't close/lock the question or mark as duplicate. The question is different scenario from others. I have read thoroughly everything for nearly 20 days and asking now.

I have 2 spinners populated from JSON (2nd spinner values based on 1st). If I click the submit button after selecting the spinner values, I should be getting a listview loaded with items from JSON.

So the concept I assumed is:

I populated the spinners, then when I click submit the spinner values are sent to PHP web service there I have written a SQL query to retrieve the data based on these spinners.

The problem is I cannot get the result. After  click submit, there is no error but I cannot go to listview.

Here's the piece of code relating to my problem.

PHP web service:

```
<?php
.......
.......
....... 

if(isset($_POST['converternumber']) && isset($_POST['zonenumber']))
{

  $n_converternumber = $_POST["converternumber"];
  $n_zonenumber = $_POST["zonenumber"];
//$n_converternumber= "2";

}
$sql_query= "select codeid from addcode where converternumber like '%".$n_converternumber."%' and zonenumber like '%".$n_zonenumber."%'";

$result= mysqli_query($connectionn,$sql_query);
..........
..........
?>
```

In mainActivity, there are 2 spinners which I can populate, I am just pasting the code of submit button's onClick method:

```
public void addflrsurvey(View view){

        st = stateSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        ci = citiesSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

        String method = "listofcodes";
        BackgroundTaskcode backgroundTaskcode = new BackgroundTaskcode(this);
        backgroundTaskcode.execute(method, st, ci);
        finish();
}
```

And the BackgroundTaskcode class has doInBackground class as follows

```
 try {
                URL url = new URL(flr_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));

                String data = URLEncoder.encode("converternumber", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(st,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("zonenumber", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(ci,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                os.close();
                InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                IS.close();

                return "wait....";
.................}
```

There is another java class called `codelist` which has code for populating the listview from the json file which is working fine, but I want it to be based on spinners value selection.

Again I sincerely request not to block me or close this. Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**
Logcat

```
11-28 14:58:32.040 3831-3880/com.example.app.spinnerdemo E/Json response: []����������������������������������������������
11-28 14:58:32.065 3831-3881/com.example.app.spinnerdemo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
    Process: com.example.app.spinnerdemo, PID: 3831
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
        at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
        at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
        at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:345)
        at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:101)
        at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:259)
        at com.example.app.spinnerdemo.codelist$FetchDataTask.doInBackground(codelist.java:61)
        at com.example.app.spinnerdemo.codelist$FetchDataTask.doInBackground(codelist.java:43)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
11-28 14:58:32.338 1664-3178/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example.app.spinnerdemo/.codelist
11-28 14:58:32.393 1664-3178/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example.app.spinnerdemo/.MainActivity
```

**Link to the Complete** [CODE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12CdF53FaHTgAPRBQ710l1dNv9G-lMVy3/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: have you checked via tools like Postman if your web api is working correctly and returning the values you expected?

Comment: yes it is working completely fine. @TouhidulIslam

Comment: have to checked on android end, LOGGING the response, if they are correct?

Comment: I got the message returned as shown in `BackgroundTaskcode` class as "wait", but then I cannot get the list

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: Still not working though @TouhidulIslam

Comment: update log cat with new issue

Comment: The Logcat is again same @TouhidulIslam, no change :(

Comment: i can't be, try with more care, check i any thing is called, which isn't supposed to be called in background

Comment: I am following the same process as when we insert the data we send the data in the form of strings to web service and same way I am sending here in the spinner selected values in the form of strings.

Comment: Whatever I trial and error, It is not helping. same again and again

Answer (score 0):

You are having this issue because you are trying to make a `Toast`, but `Toast` can only be shown from a ui thread/main thread, not background thread. Move `Toast` from `doInbackground` to `onPostExecute`

Comment: Here, the spinners part is working and list view part is working, but based on the spinner selection the list is not getting populated.

Comment: you have no spinner code for me to start with. your network call isn't supposed to work for the code you provided. if its working, why bother with so much code that works and not giving any code which doesn't work

Comment: The app is force closing. Okay I will send you the Link of the code in a moment

Comment: add logcat please on your post

Comment: Here's my code [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12CdF53FaHTgAPRBQ710l1dNv9G-lMVy3/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue with the code segment below.

```
BackgroundTaskcode backgroundTaskcode = new BackgroundTaskcode(this);
backgroundTaskcode.execute(method, st, ci);
finish();
```

You are `finishing` the `Activity` immediately after starting a background task. You should wait until the `asyncTask` completes and fires the `onPostExecute` method.

Comment: Yes, I have removed it and updated, still the same, Even you can check it [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12CdF53FaHTgAPRBQ710l1dNv9G-lMVy3/view?usp=sharing)